# Does Timescale DB supports compression for geography type?

Tags: timescaledb

We use Timescale DB to store some data received from GPS trackers.

Among the other metrics we, obviously, have the location value which is mapped to the geography(PointZ,4326) type.

I'm concerned about how this kind of data would be compressed (or would it be compressed at all).

Also it would be nice to have some detailed explanation (some useful links) on how the Timescale's compression works, what data types are supported, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

Not so long answer: It depends on how you define "support". In general TimescaleDB works with those types and they compress. However, like with PG, it'll use the base compression (lz4 as far as I know), meaning, there isn't any specific compression algorithm as for some other data types.

Answer (score -1):

You can compress any hypertable with timescaleDB.

***"When you enable compression, the data in your hypertable is compressed chunk by chunk"***

1. **step 1**. you should create your hypertable.
2. **step 2**. enable the
   compression feature by declaring which column you want to segment
   by.
3. **step 3**. Add a compression policy

You can refere to documentation of timescaleDB for more information.

Comment: The question was about compression support (and, optionally, its implementation) for the specific data type, not about compression support in general.